4S LG M50LT Voltage Sag
I have built a 4S pack using LG M50LT cells, using a 21700 4S cell holder, and a 4S BMS.
My load is a radio that draws 5 A peak, this is far under the 7.5 A max discharge.
The voltage of the pack is 16 V and when the 5 A load is connected the voltage drops to 14.6 V, this gets worse at a lower SOC at a pack voltage of 13.8 V the voltage drops to 11.8 V under load.
I do also notice that the pack voltage increases when the pack is squeezed.
Any help would be appreciated.
LG M50LT Datasheet

Can you include battery specs? or link?

I read  from www.rpe-na.com
Max. Charging Current: 4000mA (1.0C)
Max. Discharging Current: 10000mA (2.0C)  which implies 1C load = 5A and
Nominal Voltage: 3.63V  your 14.6V = 3.65  IMHO this is normal.    as well as low SOC since you are using max 1C load.  16V is the no load idle voltage which includes a double-electric layer which is a normal drop for Li

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm also seeing a 0.150V drop between the the positive terminal of the cell and the tab of the holder when the 5A load is attached.

Common current sense resistors drop near 50mV at rated current. But that is just a normal contact Rs of 30 mohms. Check for oxide and contact force

3.6V is a typical discharge plateau for an ordinary Li-Ion cell. The cut-off voltage should be about 2.7 V, or down to 10.8V for 4S. This is the inherent property of Li-Ion battery technology.
Therefore, if you want to enjoy full capacity of your battery, you should design your power subsystem to work in the full range of the battery, from fully-charged (4.35V x 4 = 17.2V) down to 10.8V.
Per m50t cell specifications, the range would be from 4.2 x 4 = 16.8V down to 10.0V (cut-off is specified as 2.5V)

The historical time for measuring battery capacity has been the standard 20h test. This offers a higher cycle life and Ah or Wh capacity. Significant degradation of Wh capacity occurs when 100% is consumed in a few hours.

From your linked 2021-02- 01 specs (not final)

2.7 Standard Discharge
CC : Constant current 0.2C (960mA) End Voltage(Cut off) 2.50V



Using less than 4h 100% use will result in a dramatic loss of capacity.
From above the 1C rate is almost 5A which you used.
If you want to improve test results pay attention to the ESR series resistance which controls your drop from nominal voltage.

Comparative results.

https://www.e-cigarette-forum.com/attachments/img_6047-jpeg.1001080/

Ref to comparative battery tests


Added
Your misc. info.
50 mV drop/ 5A = normal contact Rs of 30 mohms.
Check for oxide and contact force on holder. Clean as recommended. This is a weakness of removable types without solder tabs and your load is excessive. Relay contacts use silver alloy oxide plating for lower Rs.
